# how to extract number from string and sort using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

actually i don't know LINQ

I have the following data
201305PAR60 
201305PAR3
201306PAR4

201305PAR7
201305PAR8
201305PAR9
201305PAR10
201312PAR50


output

201305PAR3
201306PAR4
201305PAR7
201305PAR8
201305PAR9
201305PAR10
201312PAR50
201305PAR60

and sort this data depending on last digit

ie 
201305PAR**3** 
201306PAR**4**
201305PAR**7**
201305PAR**8**
201305PAR**9**
201305PAR**10**
201312PAR**50**
201305PAR**60**

Comment: Didy you try anything?

Comment: What is the consistency of the numbers? PAR3 and 4 are taken apart with 201305 and 201306. In the second series there is a PRA instead of PAR and also a 201312. I don't an easy way to get that order as output.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result1 = from s in strings
              select new
              {
                 Original = s,
                 Sort = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("PAR") + 3),
              }

var result2 = from r in result1
              orderby r.Sort
              select r.Original;
```

of course this can be streamlined a bit

```
var result = from s in strings
             orderby int.Parse(s.Substring(s.IndexOf("PAR") + 3))
             select s;
```

Comment: Sort data depending on digit present in after PAR and length is fix up to PAR ie 201305PAR (length=9) and digit after that string

Comment: feel free to replace s.IndexOf(...) with a constant. the key is to parse the last part to int and sort by the result. Otherwise you can google for `C# natural sort` but if you know how your items look you can use this code.

Answer (score 1):

This does not directly answer the question, but if you want the solution to be easily maintainable and expandable, you might want to consider creating a class for those.

```
public class Par
{
    public DateTime Date { get; private set; }
    public int Index { get; private set; }

    public Par(string input)
    {
        // define 'Date' using the first 6 chars of input
        // define 'Index' using @SchlaWiener's method
    }
}
```

After which you can easily do this:

```
var result = from par in myParList
             orderby par.Date, par.Index
             select par;
```

which would sort this:
2013**01**PAR2
2013**02**PAR1
2013**01**PAR1

to this:
2013**01**PAR1
2013**01**PAR2
2013**02**PAR1

or you can use `orderby par.Index, par.Date` instead, to achieve this:
201301PAR**1**
201302PAR**1**
201301PAR**2**